# jQuery works on manually created HTML but not jQuery created HTML?

Tags: jquery, html

I just started out with jQuery and really only need it for some very basic stuff. Here's what I'm trying to do:

I separate content into an ".overview" div and a ".detail" div. jQuery looks through all the ".detail"-divs, moves up one element (.prev(".overview")) and appends a button. Then it scales down all the ".detail" divs to zero, and uses the buttons to reveal/hide them respectively.

I had first hard-coded the buttons, but it seemed tedious and unnecessary. But as soon as I generate them dynamically, the reveal/hide function does not work anymore. I searched around, but I might not be using the right terms...

Here's my html:

```
<div class="title">
    <h2>Title</h2>
</div>
<div class="overview">
    <p>...</p>
</div>
<div class="detail">
        <p>...</p>
</div>
```

And this is the jQuery code (in a separate file):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".detail").each(function() {
        $(this).prev("div").append("<div class=\"expand\"><a href=#>more</a></div>");
        $.data(this, "realHeight", $(this).height());
    }).css({ overflow: "hidden", height: "0" });

    $(".expand").toggle(function() {
        $(this).html("<a href=#>less</a>")
        var div = $(this).next(".detail")
        div.animate({ height: div.data("realHeight")+21 }, 250);        
    }, function() {
        $(this).html("<a href=#>more</a>")
        $(this).next(".detail").animate({ height: 0 }, 250);
    });

});
```

I would hugely appreciate if you could point me in the right direction. Or, if it's a stupid one, just tell me what I need to do a search for. :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.next() get the next sibling and ".detail" is not a sibling of ".expand" in your DOM structure. You may want to get to the parent (".overview") and then get the next().

Or change the structure so that they are siblings.

**EDIT**:
In your code you do this, and that's why they are not siblings:

```
$(".detail").each(function() {
    $(this)
        .prev("div") // <- this gets the overview div
        .append("<div class=\"expand\"><a href=#>more</a></div>"); // <- this creates the "expand" as a child of the overview div (so not a sibling of details)
```

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UwvYS/) with "parent" working, using the base code in the question.

Here is another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/URzb5/1/) with the div "expand" inserted as sibling using `insertBefore`. It works exactly the same and you don't need the `.parent()` call.

Comment: Why are they not siblings? The ".overview", ".expand" and ".detail" divs are all children of the <body> element (or a Content div, if needed).

Comment: Mmmm... did you change the example? I am pretty sure when I looked into it 40 mins ago, the ".expand" div was inside the ".overview" div... It could be I got it wrong tho :/

Comment: Oh. Could be, sorry, I'm constantly updating the example trying new stuff. My bad. I'll move my playground to a new location. :)

Comment: My code would have also worked if I had used "after()" instead of "append()", just for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Yeah, that would have done it as well! :) You may want to accept the answer if it was helpful. ;)

Comment: Ah, that's what that does. :-D Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The technique you need to read about is **event delegation** - take a look at the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) functions in jQuery, depending on the version you're using.

The general principle, however, is that rather than binding your event handler to individual elements (which have to exist when the jQuery code is executed) you instead bind a single event handler to an element you know will always exist (such as the `<body>` tag) which runs a function dependent on a selector.

When you click on your button element, the click event is triggered for that element, then bubbles up the DOM, being triggered for every element it encounters on the way up. When it reaches your always present element (your `<body>` element), it checks the original target of the event against the provided selector, and only executes the code if it matches.